# Convert Json list in a dataframe using R

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to convert a Json file (json list) in a dataframe using R, I used library Rjson, Jsonlite, TidyJson and another one but later import but don't convert in dataframe using commands of the library.

Example data

```
List of 4
 $ id           : num 0
 $ description  : chr "TSA_test1-Default"
 $ feedChecksums:List of 1
  ..$ 76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f: num 3.67e+09
 $ modifications:List of 8
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ bidirectional: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ frequencies  :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ :List of 13
  .. .. .. ..$ monday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ tuesday    : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ wednesday  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ thursday   : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ friday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ saturday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ sunday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ hopTimes   : num [1:12] 235 316 354 289 271 215 275 184 326 202 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ dwellTimes : num [1:13] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ startTime  : num 14400
  .. .. .. ..$ endTime    : num 82800
  .. .. .. ..$ headwaySecs: num 380
  .. .. .. ..$ entryId    : chr "87bfbfa1-53b4-4dbd-adec-ec8e0f1d3860"
  .. .. ..$ :List of 13
  .. .. .. ..$ monday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ tuesday    : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ wednesday  : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ thursday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ friday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ saturday   : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ sunday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ hopTimes   : num [1:12] 235 316 354 289 271 215 275 184 326 202 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ dwellTimes : num [1:13] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ startTime  : num 18000
  .. .. .. ..$ endTime    : num 82800
  .. .. .. ..$ headwaySecs: num 450
  .. .. .. ..$ entryId    : chr "f27bc503-7758-488d-8b86-be57813c4485"
  .. .. ..$ :List of 13
  .. .. .. ..$ monday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ tuesday    : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ wednesday  : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ thursday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ friday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ saturday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ sunday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ hopTimes   : num [1:12] 235 316 354 289 271 215 275 184 326 202 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ dwellTimes : num [1:13] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ startTime  : num 18000
  .. .. .. ..$ endTime    : num 79200
  .. .. .. ..$ headwaySecs: num 600
  .. .. .. ..$ entryId    : chr "04ae0d95-76b4-4d56-806d-328470850cd8"
  .. ..$ stops        :List of 13
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.59
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.6
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.62
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.64
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.65
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.66
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.67
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.68
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.68
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ id: chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:5217"
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.69
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.68
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74
  .. .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ id: chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:BD-041A"
  .. ..$ type         : chr "add-trips"
  .. ..$ comment      : chr "New Route 68"
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ type     : chr "adjust-dwell-time"
  .. ..$ routes   : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--268--866"
  .. ..$ stops    : NULL
  .. ..$ dwellSecs: chr "35"
  .. ..$ comment  : chr "Adjust Dwell Time of Route 7 to Ricaurte"
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ type   : chr "adjust-speed"
  .. ..$ routes : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--10--808"
  .. ..$ hops   : NULL
  .. ..$ scale  : chr ".8"
  .. ..$ comment: chr "Reduce Speed of K16"
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ type                              : chr "adjust-frequency"
  .. ..$ route                             : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--27--827"
  .. ..$ retainTripsOutsideFrequencyEntries: logi FALSE
  .. ..$ entries                           :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ :List of 12
  .. .. .. ..$ headwaySecs: num 120
  .. .. .. ..$ startTime  : num 14400
  .. .. .. ..$ endTime    : num 36000
  .. .. .. ..$ sourceTrip : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--DLN--TM3580622--27--827--2"
  .. .. .. ..$ entryId    : chr "7c0b764b-bdd6-445b-afa8-95a47c11a86b"
  .. .. .. ..$ monday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ tuesday    : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ wednesday  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ thursday   : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ friday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ saturday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ sunday     : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ :List of 12
  .. .. .. ..$ headwaySecs: num 480
  .. .. .. ..$ startTime  : num 36000
  .. .. .. ..$ endTime    : num 54000
  .. .. .. ..$ sourceTrip : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--DLN--TM3580693--27--827--5"
  .. .. .. ..$ entryId    : chr "4d702960-3cd0-4561-a41b-61f2777d67b1"
  .. .. .. ..$ monday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ tuesday    : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ wednesday  : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ thursday   : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ friday     : logi TRUE
  .. .. .. ..$ saturday   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. ..$ sunday     : logi FALSE
  .. ..$ comment                           : chr "Convert To Frequency of C19"
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ type   : chr "adjust-speed"
  .. ..$ routes : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--264--859"
  .. ..$ hops   : NULL
  .. ..$ scale  : chr "1.3"
  .. ..$ comment: chr "Increase Speed of Route 3 to USME"
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ type                  : chr "remove-stops"
  .. ..$ stops                 : list()
  .. ..$ patterns              : chr [1:26] "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--SAB--TM3550002--40--834--10" "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--SAB--TM3550830--40--834--11" "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--SAB--TM3550126--40--834--12" "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--DLN--TM3580794--40--834--4" ...
  .. ..$ secondsSavedAtEachStop: chr "60"
  .. ..$ comment               : chr "Remove Stops from F23"
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ type   : chr "remove-trips"
  .. ..$ routes : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--41--755"
  .. ..$ comment: chr "Remove Trips from D50"
  ..$ :List of 8
  .. ..$ fromStop  : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--1908"
  .. ..$ dwellTimes: num [1:8] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25
  .. ..$ hopTimes  : num [1:7] 411 541 459 422 140 161 505
  .. ..$ routes    : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--56--114"
  .. ..$ stops     :List of 6
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.66
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.64
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.62
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.6
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.59
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 4.59
  .. .. .. ..$ lon: num -74.1
  .. ..$ toStop    : chr "76ebc256-abc5-4fe1-8be3-d6f9d0a1276f:T--1966"
  .. ..$ type      : chr "reroute"
  .. ..$ comment   : chr "Reroute L10"
```

Comment: in such scenarios, i follow Step1.`require(jsonlite);
json2 <- fromJSON(my_output, flatten = TRUE);` Step2.`library(dplyr);
df <- as_data_frame(json2);`

Comment: Can you check if the solution works with your data?

Comment: Thanks, perfect job :)

Comment: Just FYI @user2805474 - using `dput` can make the process of receiving help much easier, since users can copy / paste the code to get the data in their own environment.  There is also helpful explanation of some of the `tidyjson` verbs (for more complex data) [here](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson).  @ParthChaudhary do you want to post as an answer so it can be accepted?